# When using SimpleCV with GeoTiffs what is the best way to keep the georeferencing data?

Tags: python-2.7, gis, tiff, arcgis, simplecv

I have searched the internet at depth looking for help on this. I have two images (before and after) that are georeferened and georectifyed to be right on top of one another. I am using Simple CV hopefully for some indepth analysis and changed between the image. Right now I am just getting familiar with Simple CV and am using the blob detection. Here is my code:

```
from SimpleCV.base import *
from SimpleCV.Features import *
from SimpleCV.ImageClass import *
from SimpleCV.Display import *

var1 = Image("C:\Users\pathname\image.tif")
var1.show()

blobs = var1.findBlobs()
blobs[-1].draw() #The blobs[-1] fills in the blob
var1.show()
var1.save("C:\pathname\Blobfill1.tif")
```

I do the the blob detection on the before and after image and save them both as tifs. However when I begin to subtract to the images or even bring both images back into ArcMap, they have have lost all their spatial reference data and no long right on top of one another. It is very important that the two images stay exactly right on top of one another during my analysis period. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that SimpleCV is simply not saving the exif data in the image file. I doubt it is reading it at all when you are loading the file.

The easiest way may be to open the file as you have use something like pyexiv2 (http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/) to read the exif information including the georeferencing.

When finished save as you have and use pyexiu2 to save the georeferencing back to the saved file.